# Doctrine array hydration returns objects

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm runnig query to get all records from the table

```
     return $this
            ->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->orderBy('a.id', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

My final purpose is to convert it to json and send as response.
The problem is that I get the array of entity objects, which I get without specifying  `Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY` option. But I need to get array of arrays to convert it to json. Is it expected behavior for HYDRATE_ARRAY?

Comment: `Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY` should return array of arrays. Do you have `use Doctrine\ORM\Query` in the file? You can also try to use ` getArrayResult()` instead of `->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY)` - it's a alias for `execute(null, HYDRATE_ARRAY)`.

Comment: @pazulx, Yes, I have declaration, and `getArrayResult`also returns array of entities

Comment: @pazulx, I found the reason: my method was named findAll which is called from basic repository:)